# "Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError" when attempting to access uploaded image file in sub directory of Phoenix application

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

Phoenix/Elixir learner here :)

I tried to access an image file under sub directory (ie:dashboard) of a Phoenix application, something like :

```
http://localhost:8000/dashboard/media/tv1_1.jpg
```

but it keeps throwing me with the same error messages

```
Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError at GET /dashboard/media/tv1_1.jpg
no route found for GET /dashboard/media/tv1_1.jpg
```

Here is a snippet of my configuration setting in `endpoint.ex`

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/dashboard",
    from: :my_dashboard,
    gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)

  plug Plug.Static, at: "/media",
  from: "user_media",
  only: ~w(*.mp4 *.jpg *.jpeg *.png)
```

Also, I put upload folder (user_media) on the same level of Phoenix application's root directory.

Hope someone could pinpoint of what I've missed here.

Thanks in advance.
-dewa-

Comment: Hi @dewa19, can you share your file system structure? Specifically it would be good to see where this media folder is in relation to the project.

Comment: Hi @ElliotBlackburn, thank you for your interest. This is my project full path : `/home/dewa19/Elixir/real-project/dashboard/my_dashboard` and the media folder located inside this project folder, ie : `/home/dewa19/Elixir/real-project/dashboard/my_dashboard/user_media`. I hope, this is what you meant by "file system structure"...